# How to use form.cleaned_data django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

After form.is_valid(), we get form.cleaned_data. How can i use this cleaned data on the next page.

For example, after the form page is processed we redirect the customer to next page, where I want to use the cleaned_data's info like name, contact, address..etc fields to be shown in next page.

```
def ind(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = form_name(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print(form.cleaned_data)
            return render(request, 'app_one/abc.html', {'data': form.cleaned_data})
            # form.save(commit=True)
            # return render(request,'app_one/index.html')
    else:
        form=form_name()
    return render(request,'app_one/index.html',{'form':form)
```

Comment: could you elaborate your question with some example or an use case ?

Comment: sure, its like customer is making a purchase on the first page and we generate a receipt on the next page. So customer details which are filled on the first page need to show those details on the second page as receipt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will have a validated data after calling the `form.is_valid()` method. Once we have a validated data then we can use as we like.
For your case

> customer details which are filled on the first page need show those details on the second page as receipt.

You can create a model named `Reciept` and save the details in the model for future reference. If you want these details in the other page views then simply pass the model object in `context` to render the details.

You can use the cleaned data like below

```
def ind(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = form_name(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            context = {}.update(form.cleaned_data)
            return render(request, 'app_one/abc.html', context)
            # form.save(commit=True)
            # return render(request,'app_one/index.html')
    else:
        form=form_name()
    return render(request,'app_one/index.html',{'form':form)
```

Example Form:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
     reciept_num = forms.CharField()
```

consider above form as an example
You can access the `reciept_num` data in template using the name `reciept_num`.

Comment: Is there any way I can send the cleaned_form as a dictionary to next page and use it.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign the cleaned_data to variables as usual for forms
e.g. your_data=form.cleaned_data['your_data']

After that, pass those variables to context.
e.g. context = {
'your_data':your_data
}

Lastly return the template.
e.g. return(request,'template.html',context=context)

At the 'template.html', use the variables as {{your_data}}.